# Access Query Loop Update

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with purchase orders, and all POs could have several entries with different items associated.

| PO | PN | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Open |
| 1 | B | progress |
| 1 | C | Delivered |
| 2 | A | Open |
| 3 | A | Delivered |
| 3 | A | Delivered |

From this master data Table, I would like to create a overview table, with just one entry per PO and only one Status information, according certain criteria.

Criteria example:

- if one item is in PROGRESS or DELIVERED set PO status as PROGRESS
- if one item is in OPEN (But don't exist PROGRESS) set PO Status as OPEN.
- if all item is in PROGRESS  or DELIVERED or OPEN set PO Status as PROGRESS  or DELIVERED or OPEN accordingly.

OVERVIEW TABLE Example:

| PO | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PROGRESS |
| 2 | OPEN |
| 3 | Delivered |

Answer (score 1):

I will offer one approach to consider. Assuming there are only 3 status categories:

Query1:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.PO, 
Count(OrderDetails.PN) AS CntPN, 
Sum(IIf([Status]="Progress",1,0)) AS CntP, 
Sum(IIf([Status]="Open",1,0)) AS CntO, 
Sum(IIf([Status]="Delivered",1,0)) AS CntD
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderDetails.PO;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Query1.PO, Switch([CntP]=[CntPN],"Progress", [CntO]=[CntPN],"Open", [CntD]=[CntPN],"Delivered", CntO>0 AND CntP=0,"Open", CntP>0 Or CntD>0,"Progress", True,Null) AS S
FROM Query1;
```

Query1 could be a CROSSTAB instead of using IIf() expressions to emulate. CROSSTAB will return Null instead of 0 so would have to deal with that. Then adjust Query2 structure for different field names.

Anything else will probably need a VBA custom function.